# Configuring an Azure Static Web App to authenticate using Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, vue.js, authentication

I've built a basic Vue web app using Azure Static Web Apps, and I'm trying to configure custom authentication. I've already managed to get everything (mostly) working using Auth0 by following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad) and referencing this handy [blog post](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2021-05-13-using-auth0-with-static-web-apps/).

For Auth0, I added `AUTH0_ID=<my-auth0-id>` and `AUTH0_SECRET=<my-auth0-secret>` to the local.settings.json file. My staticwebapp.config.json looked like this:

```
...
"auth": {
      "identityProviders": {
        "customOpenIdConnectProviders": {
          "auth0": {
            "registration": {
              "clientIdSettingName": "AUTH0_ID",
              "clientCredential": {
                "clientSecretSettingName": "AUTH0_SECRET"
              },
              "openIdConnectConfiguration": {
                "wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "https://<my-auth0-tenant>/.well-known/openid-configuration"
              }
            },
            "login": {
              "nameClaimType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
              "scopes": ["openid", "profile"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm now trying to set up authentication using Azure AD B2C. My understanding is that Azure Static Web Apps handles a portion of the authentication such that I should configure the ID provider to work with a web app rather than with a single page app framework. This is what I did when using Auth0 and it seemed to work.

I've added `AADB2C_ID=<my-azure-ad-b2c-id>` and `AADB2C_SECRET=<my-azure-ad-b2c-secret>` to the local.settings.json file. In staticwebapp.config.json I replaced `ClientIdSettingName` to `AADB2C_ID`, `clientSecretSettingName` to `AADB2C_SECRET`, and `wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration` to `https://<my-azure-ad-b2>.b2clogin.com/<my-azure-ad-b2c>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_signupsignin1`. This references the 'signupsignin' user flow on my B2C tenant.

At this point I can visit /login which points to /.auth/login/aadb2c, initiates the user flow, and lets me sign up and verify as expected. The test user is then created in my Azure AD B2C tenant. However, B2C then tries to redirect me to /.auth/complete which throws a 403 error:

> We need an email address or a handle from your login service. To use
> this login, please update your account with the missing info.

I've tried adding /.auth/complete as an allowed redirect URI in Azure AD B2C but this doesn't fix things. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to this: "nameClaimType": "emails".
Sourced from staticwebapp.config.json in here: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/457